# Node gyp error even after setting the environment variable

Tags: python, node.js, node-gyp

I have set my environment variable as `PYTHON=D:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe`, but still I get the below error. This is while doing `npm install node-gyp --save`. I am not able to find a solution for it. My python version is python-3.5.6

```
gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "D:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable. 
gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:454:19) 
gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:480:16) 
gyp ERR! stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29 
gyp ERR! stack at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:112:15) 
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" 
gyp ERR! cwd D:\R04_17\FarmersMBaaS\node_modules\timekit gyp ERR! node -v v7.5.0 
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0 
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Any help would be appreciated. Need a perfect solution for removing this error.

Comment: I'm not using python nor have I every installed on this machine. I haven't changed any of my packages but all of a sudden I'm getting this error as well when running npm install

Comment: Did you try doing some tricks to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think node-gyp needs the old Python 2.7.xxx, not Python 3.xxx

see:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/746

Answer (score 0):

Configuration: window 10, 64 bit, node v8.13.0, npm v6.4.1

Follow the below steps :

1. Restart the system
2. Open cmd by administrator
3. Delete C:\Users\user_name.node-gyp
4. Delete %AppData%/npm
5. Delete %AppData%/npm-cache
6. Check out [node-gyp package](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)
7. npm install -g node-gyp
8. npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
9. node-gyp configure --python C:\Users\pcq158.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe
10. npm config set msvs_version 2017 --global
11. npm install